# Regex optional matching with letters numbers and symbols

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking for a regex pattern with the following particulars

- Case insensitive
- Only 1 letter is valid at a time
- letters be preceded by a number with an optional space
- Any symbol is valid, ie `%`,`@`,`/`,`-` etc
- It shouldn't match on 3 whole integer numbers `2342 34534 2342`. however `345345 / 435` or `236 545` is fine
- The pattern needs to match the complete string
- Multiple spaces and underscore will be cleaned up beforehand and not relevant

**Matches**

```
"1"
"12"
"12 34"
"12 a 34"
"1a"
"54b"
"32 c"
"43-23"
"45 c/34"
"45/34 d"
"67 / 345"
"23a / 56"
"12 / 56B"
```

Just to be more specific. The following should not match

```
"1 3 5"
"34 a a"
"34b s"
"56/v"
"234 / a"
"234a/a"
"34b 456s"
"34b/456s"
"34b / 456s"
```

My current attempt is `^\d+[\s]?[a-z\W]?[\s]?[\W]?[\s]?\d+?[a-z]?$`

[**You can see a demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YO2ZUB)

Although I'll most likely need more than one pattern (for the letters either side of the symbol), my main problem is trying to get the `?` to work correctly, i.e. with the current pattern I'd expect to get more positives.

**Update**

The current regex produces the following results.

```
Good list
-------------
False - 1 <= this should match
True - 12 34
True - 12 a 34
False - 1a <= this should match
True - 54b
False - 32 c <= this should match
True - 43-23
True - 45c/34
True - 45/34d
True - 67 / 345
True - 23a / 56
True - 12 / 56b

Bad list
-------------
False - 1 3 5
False - 34 a a
False - 34b s
False - 234a/a
True - 34b 456s <= these are false positives only because they have 2 letters
True - 34b/456s
True - 34b / 456s
```

Ignoring the false positives, which I can fix by creating 2 patterns, I'm stuck on why the current regex is not matching on those pointed out.

Comment: I don't understand why a single number passes, but three numbers fails.  Can you explain this?

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen, do you mean, what the logic is why i need the pattern like this? or whats causing the current regex to produce the results?

Comment: `The following should not match`: `1 3 5` ... but `12` by itself matches.  Why?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ahh ok. yeah the requirements are a little convoluted, its just the way i need to match, its fine tuning a mature ordering system to reduce some of the guff we get in the address line 1.

Comment: Then you should tell us what the actual problem is, rather than forcing everyone to speculate about what your want here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this should be more clear now, and ps your original regex was close i.e `@"^(?!.*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z])[0-9A-Za-z%@/\-]+$";`

Comment: You _still_ haven't answered my question.  Why does `12` pass but `1 3 5` fails?  What about two numbers, e.g. `1 5`?

Comment: @ahh ok yes, 2 numbers should pass, 3 number should fail, there should only be ever 1 character. the last requirement i'm guessing could be solved by 2 patterns, for the letter either side. ill update again with more input

Comment: @wp78de hi, 2 integers, 3 integers should not match. 323 45 234 is invalid, 23 45234 is valid

Comment: @TheGeneral ok, then why "56/v" is legal and "234 / a" not?

Comment: @wp78de sorry both are illegal  "56/v"  and "234 / a" fixed the typo in the question, however the .net fiddle was correct

Comment: Why does `234 / a` fail? Another requirement is there?

Comment: @ThmLee Because all letters should be have a number before them with an optional space. i.e.  `213 a` , `213 / 123 a` are valid , `234 / a` is invalid

Comment: Then, I recommend you to fix your condition which says `(letter).. follow a number or a single space` to the phrase `be preceded by a number with an optional space`. Thanks you:-)

Comment: @ThmLee thanks wording fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing from your description, I suggest the following pattern:

```
^\d+\s?(?:\W\s?\d+(?:\s?[a-z])?|(?:\d+\s?)?[a-z]?|[a-z]\s?\W\s?\d+)$
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/0KLssq/2)

Sample Code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var goodList = new List<string>{"1", "12", "12 34","12 a 34", "1a", "54b", "32 c", "43-23", "45c/34", "45/34d", "67 / 345", "23a / 56", "12 / 56b"};
        var badList = new List<string>{"1 3 5", "34 a a", "34b s", "234a/a", "34b 456s", "34b/456s", "34b / 456s"};
        var pattern = @"^\d+\s?(?:\W\s?\d+(?:\s?[a-z])?|(?:\d+\s?)?[a-z]?|[a-z]\s?\W\s?\d+)$";
        var regex = new Regex(pattern);
        Console.WriteLine("Good list");
        Console.WriteLine("-------------");
        foreach (var item in goodList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}", regex.IsMatch(item), item));
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Bad list");
        Console.WriteLine("-------------");
        foreach (var item in badList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}", regex.IsMatch(item), item));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: PERFECT! you got it just as i did, but with less regex. points awarded . mine was `^([0-9]+)[\s]?[a-z]?[\s]?([\W]?[\s]?[0-9]+)?$|^([0-9]+)[\s]?([\W]?[\s]?[0-9]+?[\s]?[a-z])?$`

Answer (score 1):

You may try this too.

```
(?im)^(?!(?:\d+\s){2}\d+\s*$)[^a-z\n]*(?:(?:\d\s?)[a-z])?[^a-z\n]*$
```

[Demo in .NET regex tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fim%29%5E%28%3F!%28%3F%3A%5Cd%2B%5Cs%29%7B2%7D%5Cd%2B%5Cs*%24%29%5B%5Ea-z%5Cn%5D*%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3A%5Cd%5Cs%3F%29%5Ba-z%5D%29%3F%5B%5Ea-z%5Cn%5D*%24&i=1%0D%0A12%0D%0A12%2034%0D%0A12%20a%2034%0D%0A1a%0D%0A54b%0D%0A32%20c%0D%0A43-23%0D%0A45%20c%2F34%0D%0A45%2F34%20d%0D%0A67%20%2F%20345%0D%0A23a%20%2F%2056%0D%0A12%20%2F%2056B%0D%0A%0D%0A2342%2034534%202342%0D%0A345345%20%2F%20435%0D%0A236%20545%203%0D%0A%0D%0A1%203%205%0D%0A34%20a%20a%0D%0A34b%20s%0D%0A56%2Fv%0D%0A234%20%2F%20a%0D%0A234a%2Fa%0D%0A34b%20456s%0D%0A34b%2F456s%0D%0A34b%20%2F%20456s),,, please click tabs, `[table]` and `[context]` for more infomation of matching.

Comment: This is a pretty neat solution too, with some smart things going on

Comment: Thanks for your interesting question:-)